# tsclean not working on single vector data

Tags: r, outliers

I have a simple dataset as attached. I see a clear outlier, (Qty=6), which should get corrected after processing it through `tsclean`.

```
c(6, 187, 323, 256, 289, 387, 335, 320, 362, 359, 426, 481, 
     356, 408, 497, 263, 330, 521, 406, 350, 478, 320, 339)
```

What I have:

```
library(forecast)

data1 <- read_csv("sample.csv", col_names = FALSE)
count_qty <-ts(data1, frequency = 12)
data1$clean_qty = tsclean(count_qty)
```

and the data returns

```
 X1 clean_qty[,"X1"]
<dbl>            <dbl>
 1     6                6
 2   187              187
 3   323              323
 4   256              256
 5   289              289
 6   387              387
 7   335              335
 8   320              320
 9   362              362
 10   359              359
 # ... with 13 more rows
```

The first item should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove outliers using `boxplot`:

```
vec1[! vec1 %in% boxplot(vec1, plot = F)$out]
 # [1] 323 256 289 387 335 320 362 359 426 481 356 408 497 263 330 521 406 350 478 320 339
```

Note that `187` is also an outlier. As you said, `6` is the obvious one;

[image]